# Solving PDEs with complicated boundary conditions

Tags: symbolic, physics, differential-equations

The system I'm trying to solve is
$$\nabla^2 C_{(r,\theta)} =0$$
$$C_{(\infty,\theta)}=C_0$$
$$ [ \frac{\partial C_{(r,\theta)}}{\partial r} \cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial C_{(r,\theta)}}{\partial\theta} \sin(\theta) ]|_{r=a*\cos(\theta)}=\frac{k}{D}C_{(r,\theta)}|_{r=a*\cos(\theta)}$$
and I have no idea how to enter the bottom equation into Mathematica. The problem I have is the inclusion of the boundary condition. How can I indicate to Mathematica that I want the derivatives to be taken and then have everything evaluated on the sphere $r=a*\cos(\theta)$ ?

Comment: I talked about solving PDEs on non-rectangular domains [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34683/solve-a-pde-on-a-domain-omega-with-given-boundary-conditions/35212#35212) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39402/nonrectangular-region-for-ndsolve/39491#39491). Note v10 seems to have added some new functionality, at least for numerical solutions.